# Terraform - for_each with if-clause and different tuples

Tags: terraform, azure-active-directory

i have a problem with a data-block in my terraform script:
[Terraform-Error-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHcz.png)

```
data "azuread_users" "ownerids" 
{
for_each = {for appregistration in (var.TenantName == "prodTenant" ? local.appregistrations_prod : local.appregistrations_dev) : appregistration.name => appregistration}
user_principal_names = each.value.owners
}
```

i have in production-environment (50) more app registrations as in dev-environment (30). terraform gives an error that the two tuples have not exactly the same length...

somebody knows a solution? - the length of the tuples must be different.

thanks and best regards

terraform gives an error that the two tuples have not exactly the same length...

Comment: Is Terraform complaining about the code in your question, or about a reference to that data source later in your code somewhere? Ideally you would edit your question to include the actual error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying a local variable to decide which tuple will be used.

Example:

```hcl
locals {
  // ...

  result = var.TenantName == "prodTenant" ? local.appregistrations_prod : local.appregistrations_dev
}

data "azuread_users" "ownerids" 
{
  for_each = {for appregistration in local.result : appregistration.name => appregistration}
}
```

Funny enough, I was not able to reproduce the problem. To me, it accepted a decision between 2 differently sized tuples on the for_each expression level as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
i tried your proposal but there is still the same error for the result-variable :(
can you share your functional code?
Which terraform version do you have? i updated to 1.5.0 but it doesnt matter...

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a situation where the configuration doesn't give Terraform enough information to infer what types you intended, and so Terraform is making an incorrect assumption. Specifically, you've presumably written a pair of local values that use the `[ ... ]` syntax which constructs a tuple, and Terraform wasn't able to find an element type that all of the elements of those two tuples have in common and so assumes you intended to write tuples rather than lists.

You can help Terraform understand your intent by explicitly converting the two tuples to lists:

```
locals {
  appregistrations_prod = tolist([
    # your elements as before
  ])
  appregistrations_dev = tolist([
    # your elements as before
  ])
}
```

*Just* adding those `tolist` calls will probably cause a new error, but one that is closer to describing the root cause. Specifically, I expect Terraform will complain that not all of the elements of the tuples have the same type and therefore conversion to list isn't possible. You can then fix whatever is making the element types inconsistent so that they all match, and then conversion to list should succeed and the conditional expression should also succeed (choosing between two lists of the same element type).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I think that the problem occurs because of my local-variables:

`appregistrations_prod = [
{
dname = "appreg-1"
owners = ["owner1", "owner2"]
notes = ""
web = {
redirect_uris = ["https://xxxx.de/"]
implicit_grant = {
access_token_issuance_enabled = false
id_token_issuance_enabled = false}
}
}]`

Some of my app registrations have a web-config and others not. can i declare my local-variables as the normal variables in my variables.tf-file?

Comment: You can set the unused attributes explicitly to `null` to allow the element types to match. `null` can convert to any type, so Terraform should be able to infer that `web`'s element type is that object type as long as you include that attribute and set it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is that you can not declare variables in locals.tf but in the terraform.tfvars-file. then terraform knows all properites of the variable and you can define optional settings.